# How to easily change my <header> and <footer> on multiple pages?

Tags: php, html, header

I am currently building a personal website aiming at showcasing some of my work in translation and writing.
No fancy stuff, just basic HTML / CSS

As I started building up sections ("Translations", "Blog") I realised how troublesome it was to update each header and footer on every single page.

So I googled solutions for this and the most recurrent answer was to use PHP. Fast forward today after taking a PHP 101 class, I am having a slight grasp on the mechanics of PHP.

I created a header.php and a footer.php file and proceeded to add

`<?php include('header.php'); ?>`

in my index.html

But then I would need to change this file extension to .php in order to read it.

THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING LOST
Do I need to change all my html files to php ? When I googled this, some people on here claimed that would slow down my website and so on...
I don't know what I should do and I am kinda lost.

So what would you suggest being the most efficient tool for me to update my little website with the less struggle. Are there more recent technologies that would be more suitable?

Comment: You are saying yourself that your website is a "little website". I assume converting to PHP won't slow it down appreciably

Comment: Yes, a page that is PHP, ASP.Net, Javs Server Pages, or other dynamic content puts more of a load on a server than a plain HTML file, which is a static file that is just read and sent to the client.  Script files must be executed by a process server-side then the results are sent as the response.  However, if you look at the websites you visit almost all of them do this.  Try to find any sites that serve static HTML pages and they are probably some open source project where they don't expect much traffic and don't care how it looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way is to rename all the HTML files to PHP so that your server knows that it needs to process the files thru the PHP interpreter.

Alternatively, you may use JS to include the header.php for your case

1. First put a div to the place where you want to show the header.php

```
<div class="secdiv"></div>
```

2. Then, use JS to load the php code to the div (just put the JS script to the end of the HTML)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function (){
 $(".secdiv").load("content.php");
});
</script>
```

So this is the HTML code:

```
<div class="secdiv"></div>


This is a test


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function (){
 $(".secdiv").load("content.php");
});
</script>
```

and this is the content.php :

```
<?php

echo "Header here....";
echo "<hr>";
?>
```

You may see the effect thru this [sandbox](https://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/subx/testSO3Oct2023.html)

Now, you may do the same for the `footer.php` ......